# KOMA-Script: change font of sectioning headings to serif

Tags: fonts, sectioning, formatting, koma-script

How to change the default `KOMA-Script` font that is used for chapter/section headings etc. to the Computer Modern font that is used in text body?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont`. See section 3.6 of the `KOMA-Script` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% Variant A: Default plus roman (i.e., still bold)
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

% Variant B: Ecactly as in the text body (i.e., not bold)
% \setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{bar}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @umar: The `disposition` element controls all sectioning levels (including `\chapter`). See my updated example.

Comment: sorry, actually fncychap was retaining the koma font for chapter title

Answer (score 14):

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

Answer (score 13):

As was suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289867/62498), there is also an option that can be set that also modifies the size of the headings slightly to match that of the standard classes.

```
\documentclass[headings=standardclasses]{scrartcl}
```