# Set default Koma script font to Times

Tags: fonts, sectioning, formatting, koma-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KOMA-Script: change font of sectioning headings to serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25845/koma-script-change-font-of-sectioning-headings-to-serif)

I am using `scrbook` document class but want to change the default font to Times.
However when I add:

```
\usepackage{times}
```

to the preamble, it does not change the font of the **chapter**, **section** or the **ToC**, but only the text. Am I missing something?

Comment: @doncherry I swear I've looked for an "original" before I answered this. Voted to close.

Comment: @lockstep: That's quite alright, you don't have to apologize to me `:)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, the `KOMA-Script` classes will typeset sectioning headings in sans-serif (and bold, `\sffamily\bfseries`), so changing the serif font to Times won't affect those headings. To switch to serif for headings, use `\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}`. You should also replace the obsolete `times` package with [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for the super fast reply!

Comment: An alternative to `mathptmx` is the new `newtx` package, `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

Answer (score 2):

The font family is set to `\sffamily` for sectional titles. You can modify `\sectfont` for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{times}% http://ctan.org/pkg/times
\renewcommand*\sectfont{\normalcolor\bfseries}% removed \sffamily
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\end{document}​
```

However, the [`times` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/times) is superseded by [`mathptmx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) that provides math support in Times as well. Lockstep's answer is perhaps more Koma-Script-y.

Comment: `\sectfont` looks like a user command, but isn't documented.

Comment: If I am using `lualatex` with `fontspec`, how can I change the font of every element to times new roman?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: What do you mean by "every element"?

Comment: I mean text body, title page, chapter/section/... etc.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: You probably need `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just found in my case that I need also `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}` since `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}` seemed to affect only the text body. Anyway, many thanks for your consideration.