# titlehead disappears with titling-package

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, titles, titlesec, titling

I would need a titlehead on my title page (see related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615478/244928)) *and*, format the title page with the titling packages. Unfortunately the titlehead disappears when the titling package is loaded.

Is there any way to add a header for the title page with the titling-package?

P.S. For some reason \thetitle does not display the main title, either, but the latest (subsub)section header. These issues could be interrelated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

%----------------------

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\huge \centering \bfseries }
\posttitle{\par \vspace{\baselineskip}} % 


\preauthor{\centering \normalsize}
\postauthor{\par}

%--------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % for editing titles
% Following formats titles
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}



%----------------------------------
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{newtxtext} % text in Times font
\usepackage{newtxmath} % math in Times font
\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries} % Makes sure everything, even fonts are in Times font
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\titlehead{THIS NEEDS TO BE DISPLAYED \hfill} 
\title{Main Title}
\subtitle{Sub Title}
\author[1,2,*]{First Author}
\author[1,2]{Second Author}
\author[1,3]{Third Author}
\author[2,4]{Supervisor Author}
\affil[1]{University}
\affil[2]{College}
\affil[3]{Institute}
\affil[4]{School \break}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: first@university.com \newline Contributing authors: second@college.com, third@institute.com, supervisor@school.com}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    
    Reference to the title, which is:  \thetitle % dependent on the titling-package
    
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `titling` package redefines `\maketitle`. Therefore it breaks the usage of KOMA-Script command `\titlehead`.

You can use package `scrlayer` or `scrlayer-scrpage` to add the title head:

```latex
\usepackage{scrlayer}% or scrlayer-scrpage which loads scrlayer
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  headsep,
  foreground,
  contents={%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
      \usekomafont{titlehead}{\csname @titlehead\endcsname\par}%
    \end{minipage}\par}
]{titlehead}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlehead}
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{\thispagestyle{titlepage}}
```

Important remark: Do not use package `titlsec` together with a KOMA-Script class. It breaks KOMA-Script features. Therefore you will get a bunch of warnings and maybe errors. Additionally this package defines an own `\thetitle`. So it is the reason for your second issue.

Here is a suggestion replacing your `titlesec` settings by KOMA-Script commands:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot,% <- added
  sfdefaults=false% <- added (replaces \setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}), needs version 3.39 or newer
]{scrartcl}


%----------------------

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\huge \centering \bfseries }
\posttitle{\par \vspace{\baselineskip}} % 
\preauthor{\centering \normalsize}
\postauthor{\par}

\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont\itshape\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot\hspace{1em}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionformat}{\thesubsection\autodot\hspace{1em}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionformat}{\thesubsubsection\autodot\hspace{1em}}

\usepackage{scrlayer}% or scrlayer-scrpage which loads scrlayer
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  headsep,
  foreground,
  contents={%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
      \usekomafont{titlehead}{\csname @titlehead\endcsname\par}%
    \end{minipage}\par}
]{titlehead}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlehead}
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{\thispagestyle{titlepage}}


%----------------------------------
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{newtxtext} % text in Times font
\usepackage{newtxmath} % math in Times font
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\titlehead{THIS NEEDS TO BE DISPLAYED \hfill} 
\title{Main Title}
\subtitle{Sub Title}
\author[1,2,*]{First Author}
\author[1,2]{Second Author}
\author[1,3]{Third Author}
\author[2,4]{Supervisor Author}
\affil[1]{University}
\affil[2]{College}
\affil[3]{Institute}
\affil[4]{School \break}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: first@university.com \newline Contributing authors: second@college.com, third@institute.com, supervisor@school.com}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Reference to the title, which is:  \thetitle. % dependent on the titling-package
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*Update:*

If the title page should use the same footer like other pages, load package `scrlayer-scrpage` and add the footer layers to the new layer page style:

```latex
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  headsep,
  foreground,
  contents={%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
      \usekomafont{titlehead}{\csname @titlehead\endcsname\par}%
    \end{minipage}\par}
]{titlehead}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlehead}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
  \Ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot}{\AddLayersToPageStyle{titlepage}{#1}}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{\thispagestyle{titlepage}}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc,
  numbers=noenddot,% <- added
  sfdefaults=false% <- added (replaces \setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries}), needs version 3.39 or newer
]{scrartcl}

%----------------------

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\huge \centering \bfseries }
\posttitle{\par \vspace{\baselineskip}} % 
\preauthor{\centering \normalsize}
\postauthor{\par}

\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\normalfont\itshape\fontsize{14}{12}\selectfont}

\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{\thesection\autodot\hspace{1em}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionformat}{\thesubsection\autodot\hspace{1em}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionformat}{\thesubsubsection\autodot\hspace{1em}}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\DeclareNewLayer[%
  headsep,
  foreground,
  contents={%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
      \usekomafont{titlehead}{\csname @titlehead\endcsname\par}%
    \end{minipage}\par}
]{titlehead}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{titlepage}{titlehead}
\ForEachLayerOfPageStyle{scrheadings}{%
  \Ifstrstart{#1}{scrheadings.foot}{\AddLayersToPageStyle{titlepage}{#1}}%
}
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{\thispagestyle{titlepage}}


%----------------------------------
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{newtxtext} % text in Times font
\usepackage{newtxmath} % math in Times font
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\titlehead{THIS NEEDS TO BE DISPLAYED \hfill} 
\title{Main Title}
\subtitle{Sub Title}
\author[1,2,*]{First Author}
\author[1,2]{Second Author}
\author[1,3]{Third Author}
\author[2,4]{Supervisor Author}
\affil[1]{University}
\affil[2]{College}
\affil[3]{Institute}
\affil[4]{School \break}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: first@university.com \newline Contributing authors: second@college.com, third@institute.com, supervisor@school.com}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Reference to the title, which is:  \thetitle. % dependent on the titling-package
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted to keep page numbers on the title page? The current solution is great, but would like to have the option to include the page number - starting from 1 on the title page - for some journals.

Comment: @SamuelSaari See the update in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue can be solved with the fancyhdr package. It would, however be better not to introduce yet another package for formatting title.

The \thetitle problem still persists.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,bibliography=totoc]{scrartcl}

%----------------------

\usepackage{titling}
\pretitle{\huge \centering \bfseries }
\posttitle{\par \vspace{\baselineskip}} % 


\preauthor{\centering \normalsize}
\postauthor{\par}

%--------------------------------

\usepackage{titlesec} % for editing titles
% Following formats titles
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{12}\itshape}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}



%----------------------------------
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{newtxtext} % text in Times font
\usepackage{newtxmath} % math in Times font
\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries} % Makes sure everything, even fonts are in Times font
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\titlehead{THIS NEEDS TO BE DISPLAYED \hfill} 
\title{Main Title}
\subtitle{Sub Title}
\author[1,2,*]{First Author}
\author[1,2]{Second Author}
\author[1,3]{Third Author}
\author[2,4]{Supervisor Author}
\affil[1]{University}
\affil[2]{College}
\affil[3]{Institute}
\affil[4]{School \break}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: first@university.com \newline Contributing authors: second@college.com, third@institute.com, supervisor@school.com}
\date{\today}

%-----Added-------
\fancypagestyle{fancyfirstpage}
{
    \fancyhf{} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \lhead{\mytitlehead}
}

%--------

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{fancy} %ADDED
    
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    
    Reference to the title, which is:  \thetitle % dependent on the titling-package
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]