# How to use Koma-script only to change font size?

Tags: fontsize, koma-script, extsizes

I've been using `\documentclass{article}`, but would like to set a default font outside the range of that document class.

The recommended solution I found on tex.exchange was to use KOMA-script, but this has changed the default font and somehow made my document longer.

**Is it possible to change the document font size** (using KOMA-script or otherwise) **in such a way that does not require additional tweaks?** If not, how can I at least make the font in KOMA-script `scrartcl` match the default in `article`?

**EDIT** In my defence, the linked answers are somewhat lacking:

1. First solution suggests `\usepackage{scrextend}` but the example\commands\syntax are not commented or explained, nor is any reference linked. While providing a starting point, this would require one to find appropriate documentation for this package that addresses this particular use (= v. difficult for novice).
2. Second solution suggests `extsizes` followed by a quote from the documentation (again without linking to it so that one could read further for clarification) *discouraging* its use for ambiguous reasons (nb this is at least the second place `extsizes` was discouraged w/o explanation, even though it was the solution I was personally looking for (as far as I know!)). Related to the lack of linked reference, no examples are provided, which leaves a novice to continue searching w/o knowing what exactly they are looking for.
3. Third solution suggests changing the document class (`scrreport`), which does not address the question posted here.
4. ibid. (change to memoir)

It seems to me, from my limited vantage point, that there are likely many tangential, more advanced, issues related to this problem; a problem very likely to present itself to novice users ill-equipped to understand, sort or evaluate the various solutions as they are stated.

To clarify: **I believe the primary audience for this question is relatively novice users; whereas the proposed solutions, IMHO, are not well suited to that audience**.

This problem seems like a great stepping stone for users to advance their knowledge, I'd suggest a well-documented Q&A that facilitates that process (& would be happy to take this on, if anyone can point me to the appropriate resources).

Comment: another option would be `extarticle` which is more like `article` than `scrartcl` but has more size options 8 9 10 11 12 14 17 20

Comment: Hi! Would this help you? [How to specify font size less than 10pt (or more than 12pt)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt-or-more-than-12pt)

Comment: @tohecz, no that is the post I refer to in my question. Thank you anyhow.

Comment: @lockstep IMHO those two questions (the one you link and the one I link) should be merged.

Comment: I read both of those posts prior to asking my question (_hence_ my problem!); unfortunately I did not try the `extarticle` class b/c the primary answer recommends KOMA over the 'extsizes', so I assumed it was better practice for reasons beyond my knowledge. After decrypting the 2nd answer, I realized that it was not actually a solution to the posted question (defines a new font-size, but does not define _the_ font of the document such that other font-size commands will scale). Having spent >1.5h trying to resolve this, IMHO an clear (ie accessible), concise solution would be very helpful.

Comment: Re item 1 of your edit: I added a link to the relevant documentation to my answer.

Comment: @lockstep thank you, I'm sure that will prove helpful to others.

Comment: @toh Relative as it is, I'm not sure _clarity_ is as useful a concept as 'comprehensive'. This problem will attract novices, and existing answers could _easily_ be adapted to provide the info in a more accessible way. I spent nearly 2h trying to change the font size, even with >1000pg of technical typesetting behind me. Newbs like me can't filter relevant info in searches and 250pg manuals as effectively as experienced members. My suggestions are very concrete and easy-to-implement solutions to facilitate accessibility in light of the _most likely_ audience for the problem w/o ignoring others.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't change the default font except for the headers, where KOMA-Script correctly (at least in my opinion) uses Sans Serif fonts for bold headings. This make it easier for the eyes, but that's only my opinion.

However, you can change the fonts of the headers via a powerfull command:

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

More information on this is  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25845/koma-script-change-font-of-sectioning-headings-to-serif).

If this is still not enough, could you clarify, how exactly KOMA-Script changes the font? Also, you can still happily use:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

If Computer modern fonts are what you are after.

**Update:** Just an update on the font sizes. One can use the something as follows:

```
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt}
```

Note, that one can pass more arguments to set other defaults for the documentclass instead of passing it whilst defining the document class.

Hence a minimal example would be as follows (you should get something similar to the default settings with article class):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\KOMAoptions{%
    %draft,
    DIV=calc, % this will calculate correct margins
    fontsize=10pt,
}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}

... TEXT ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: `KOMA-Script` classes use a default font size of 11pt, while the standard classes use 10pt.