# XeLatex with Koma-script and Minion Pro font

Tags: xetex, koma-script, fontspec

I am trying to use Minion Pro together with XeLatex and KOMA-script, setting a PhD thesis for a friend of mine.

The usage of KOMA-script obviously speaks against the use of `\setmainfont`.
However, the use of `\addtokomafont` doesn't work the way I try.

```
\addtokomafont{\normalfont}{Minion Pro}
```

I have two questions:

- will `\normalfont` change also the font of headings and so on?
- 'Minion Pro' as used with `\setmainfont` might not to work with `\addtokomafont`... How to find the name to be used?

I am working on a Mac and the Minion Pro fonts are installed and activated.

Since I just started to get things ready, the preamble is very minimalistic still.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=true}
\addtokomafont{\normalfont}{Minion Pro}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Here will be your text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but why do you think you shouldn't use `\setmainfont` with KOMA?

Comment: Because, when I tried (obvioulsy the wrong way) it wasn't working. But @Thérèse came around with two great examples on how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fontspec` plays well with `KOMA-Script`.  Here’s an example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=true}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[
  Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
% or
% \addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
% or, for bold headings,
% \addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Here will be your text.
\end{document}
```

To change the fonts used in the headings, you need to use `\setkomafont{disposition}{...}` or `\addtokomafont{disposition}{...}`. And as [lockstep explains here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25850/7883), `\normalfont` gives you what’s used by default for the body of the document; in your case, because of the choice you’ve made with `\setmainfont`, that’s Minion Pro in the regular weight. If you want Minion Pro in bold weight, `\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}` gives you what’s used by default for headings (bold sans), except that they’ll no longer use a sans but rather the roman family you’ve chosen.

If you want headings in something other than the default bold sans or the main font, use whatever font-switch name you assign to the font with `fontspec`’s `\newfontface` command. For example (a perfectly tasteless example),

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{twoside=true}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[
  Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional}]
\newfontface\chancery{TeX Gyre Chorus}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\chancery}
% or
% \addtokomafont{disposition}{\chancery}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
Here will be your text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your fast and great help. Works like a charm and I learned again a bit more!