# Apa style (biblatex) - Italics where there shouldn't be any

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm almost ready to turn in my master thesis, but there are some kinks I'm having trouble ironing out.  For example, for some mysterious reason article titles are italicized in the bibliography, which is a violation of the APA style.  As far as I understand, this should not be happening.  A separate question is why my headings in a sans serif font instead of the default, but I've pretty much given up on figuring that one out. Please advise.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[american, 12pt, a4paper,headsepline,headinclude,oneside,bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}              % T1 fonts für gute pdf-Ausgabe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       % deutsche Umlaute, []
\usepackage[ngerman, USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=authoryear, maxcitenames=3{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,unpublished,misc]{title}{\textit{#1}}


\addbibresource{../5Literature/refs.bib}


\begin{document}

Testing APA-style bibliography, citing \cite{rosenstock1974historical} and \cite{abras2004user}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting PDF]

Comment: Remove the `article` from your `\DeclareFieldFormat` command.

Comment: Ok, so that was the dumbest question ever :) thanks.  A demonstration of how you don't notice the obvious things once you've looked at them too many times...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You seem to be asking two [or more] unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Comment: About the non-serif headings: try `\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrbook}`

Comment: @samcarter (-: || You're using a KOMA-script class. The way to solve your problem is thus to dive into... [the documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)! Have a look at §3.6 *"Text Markup"* and look for `\addtokomafont{}{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following line in your code:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,unpublished,misc]{title}{\textit{#1}}
```

This says to make the titles of articles, unpublished things, and misc italics. (Independently you should not do it this way.)

You need to remove `article` from this command.  But the proper way to do this is:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished,misc]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

For the sake of completeness I'll add the part about sans serif headings (which is the KOMA default).  Some of us here don't like this, and an option in homage of this fact has been included in the class to turn them off:

```
\documentclass[egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrbook}
```

See also [KOMA-Script: change font of sectioning headings to serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25845/2693) for more conventional ways.