# Change font of section titles (scrreprt document)

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titles, fontspec, scrreprt

I'm having trouble changing the font of (sub)section titles in my document, I'd like it to be the same as the font used for the main text but as of now, a sans serif font is used for titles and a serif font for the text. I have found some answers here regarding title fonts but they did not work on my document (I suppose because I am using the scrreprt class?). Any help would be much appreciated, especially a solution which a beginner like me can use because I don't have much experience and had difficulties implementing some solutions I read about. Thank you!

So far, my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
 \usepackage{textcomp}

\addtokomafont{section}{\small}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\small}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\small}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Avenir Light}  %tried this to use sans serif font in text but it only worked in Luatex and that caused some other formatting issues
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Did you already  have a look at the answers to [KOMA-Script: change font of sectioning headings to serif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25845/134144)?

Comment: This was unexpectedly easy and worked right away, thank you so much! Sorry for the probably stupid question, I'm still learning :)

Comment: Don't worry. Most of the times it is a lot easier to find an answer  if one already knows what the necessary commands are called.

Comment: Should the font be changed for chapters and parts too?

Comment: @esdd: Originally yes, I wanted to choose the font myself and have the same font for everything. Since that proved to be difficult for me, I was happy with the default and leandriis's solution